# winsock error 10038 coming in the fourth attempt to run the server

Tags: c++, winsock

i have created a 4 client and 1 server asynchronous application in which the server is updating the 4 clients something about them by creating a position matrix of 4by4 and sending it to all clients.

The application runs successfully for first three updates and after that it stops working and stops updating and sending updates to the clients and when I tried to find the error using `WSAGetLastError()` at the receiving side of one client , exactly at the fourth time , the error I got is `10038 :- WSAENOTSOCK` , operation on socket which is actually not a socket.

I want to tell you that I am a complete beginner to socket programming so please make the explanation easy enough to understand.

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).